# how to install Ubuntu on top of CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos

Now I have server which installed CentOS, and I want to install Jupyter hub which can only be installed on Ubuntu, is there a way to install Ubuntu on top of CentOS, not side by side?

Answer (score 4):

You're misinformed about **JupyterHub's** installation requirements. According to their docs, the only requirements are Linux and python v3.5 or newer. Here are the installation instructions:

Via **pip**

```
python3 -m pip install jupyterhub
npm install -g configurable-http-proxy
python3 -m pip install notebook  # needed if running the notebook servers locally
```

Via **conda**

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub  # installs jupyterhub and proxy
conda install notebook  # needed if running the notebook servers locally
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. jupyterhub installed in centos will have problem of remote visiting. while jupyterhub on ubuntu have not.

Comment: Hmmm...that's a whole nother question. I would open a new one, detailing what happens when you try to access your notebook remotely.